# JQuery Tool tips

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I want to create a tool tip for an image with a link now I had it working one but it doesn't work with the 2nd image.

Here is my Sample Code:

```
<!-- trigger element. a regular workable link --> 
<a id="test" title="Name - Title">Name</a> 

<!-- tooltip element --> 
<div class="tooltip"> 
 <div><span class="name">Name</span><br />
Title
<span><a href="#">more info»</a></span></div>
</div>

<!-- trigger element. a regular workable link -->
<a id="test2" title="Name - Title">Name</a> 

<!-- tooltip element --> 
<div class="tooltip2"> 
 <div><span class="name">Name</span><br />
Title
<span><a href="#">more info»</a></span></div>
</div>
```

and here is my script that makes it all happens:

```
<script>
// What is $(document).ready ? See: http://flowplayer.org/tools/using.html#document_ready

$(document).ready(function() {

 // enable tooltip for "test" element. use the "slide" effect
 $("#test").tooltip({ 
 effect: 'slide',
    offset: [50, 40] }); 

 $("#test2").tooltip2({ 
 effect: 'slide',
    offset: [50, 40] }); 
});
</script>
```

but not working please help. here is the [sample](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/any-html.html) Jquery I am trying todo

Comment: If you include jquery-plugins as a tag you should mention the plugin(s) you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("#test2").tooltip({ // You had .tooltip2
 effect: 'slide',
    offset: [50, 40] }); 
});
```

**Explanation:**

The tooltip plugin provides a function called `tooltip` that is part of the jQuery object.  Once you load jquery and the tooltip plugin, every jquery object you create [FYI: `$(selector)` creates a jquery object] can call that function on itself.

When you call `tooltip2()` you are calling a function that does not exist, and so nothing happens.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't get it.. sorry im new to this jquery stuff

Comment: @kwek-kwek ... updated my answer -- let me know if you need / would like more.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the tooltip plugin -- how does it know which div to move?  It looks like it will always use the first div.

Comment: @Kathy; `tooltip` is called on the element or set of elements you want to turn into a tooltip, rather than on the element you want to turn into a tooltip. To quote http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip : `The content of a tooltip is by default the title of the element, with the href or src attribute below it, if present.`

Answer (score 0):

I would try this for the html...

```
<!-- trigger element. a regular workable link --> 
<a id="test" title="Name - Title">Name</a> 

<!-- tooltip element --> 
<div class="tooltip"> 
 <div><span class="name">Name</span><br />
Title
<span><a href="#">more info»</a></span></div>
</div>

<!-- trigger element. a regular workable link -->
<a id="test2" title="Name - Title">Name</a> 

<!-- tooltip element --> 
<div class="tooltip"> 
 <div><span class="name">Name</span><br />
Title
<span><a href="#">more info»</a></span></div>
</div>
```

and this for the javascript...

```
<script>
// What is $(document).ready ? See: http://flowplayer.org/tools/using.html#document_ready

$(document).ready(function() {

 // enable tooltip for "test" element. use the "slide" effect
 $("#test, #test2").tooltip({ 
 effect: 'slide',
    offset: [50, 40] }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: didn't work and plus #test2 has a different information to be shown